# Adding toolbar item or button on DetailViewController ToolBar for iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4, uitoolbar

How can a toolbar item be added to the toolbar found in the DetailViewController (right side in the SplitViewController  ) for iPad

Comment: Please guide me how can I change views of DetailViewcontroller (Right side of SplitViewController) programmatically without changing the RootViewController(left side) in iPad using Xcode 4

Answer (score 1):

You can customize your detailView in the detailViewController class itself.